# How do troubleshooting inherit a field in Odoo12 (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: inheritance, field, odoo, odoo-12

I'm going to add a gender field to the `res.users` model using inherit in Odoo, but whatever I do get an internal server error, please help me. Thanks in advance

Python code:

```py
from odoo import models, fields


class UsersInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.users"
    x_gender = fields.Selection(string="Gender", required=True, selection=[("male", "Male"), ("female", "Female")])
```

XML code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="resusersinherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">erfan.usersinherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.users</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="login" position="after">
                <h3>
                    <field name="x_gender"/>
                </h3>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Hi Erfan Can you paste your error ?

Comment: im get 500 Internal Server Error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have upgraded the module in apps without restarting the odoo server.

Now to fix the `500 Internal Server Error.`

1. Comment the inherit view
2. Upgrade the module via `cli` command:

   `./odoo-script.py -c config_file -d db_name -u your_module_name`
3. Now your error will be fixed
4. Uncommnet the view code then restart odoo server and then upgrade the module

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello. I've been running this command for about an 1 hour now but cli hasn't responded yet. (I work in windows) thank you